# Maximum value from pancakes glutton

Tags: c++

I have seen some posts on stackoverflow. But they are getting me confused. I couldn't understand logic behind. Therefore I am asking this question:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{   
    int pancakes[10] = {   0};
    int z = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int c = 1;
    int temp;

    do
    {   
        cout << "Please enter the number of pancakes eaten by person " << c++ << " : ";
        cin >> z;
        cout << "Person " << i << " eaten " << z << " cakes in morning! " << endl;
        pancakes[i] = z;

        i++;
    }while ( i < 10);

    for ( i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    { //For loop to search person eaten maximum pancakes

        if ( pancakes[i]>temp)
        {   
            temp = pancakes[i];
            cout << "The person who eaten most number is " << temp <<endl;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

For loop prints the maximum number on screen but it also prints some other values.
When I get the maximum value how could it print the person who eaten most number of Pancakes? for example, if person 6 has eaten most pancakes. Then it should print, person 6 eaten most pancakes.
I am using Devcpp IDE. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to print _only_ the number of the person who has eaten the most, you should not print things while you're still in the business of determining who this person is.

Comment: Also, are your persons numbered 0 to 9, or 1 to 9. Your program seems unsure.

Comment: That was some pretty freaky code there, man. Please check it and confirm that I didn't change the intent while straightening it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem:

The variable names are horrible. A good variable name describes what the variable represents. No one looking at this code can tell you what z is without reading through the code to see how it is used.

`temp`, which seems to store the largest number of pancakes eaten, is uninitialized. This will result in all sorts of wacky behaviour. Easily fixed:

```
int temp = 0;
```

or better

```
int mostPancakesEaten = 0;
```

The final for loop will print out the current pancake eater every time it finds an eater who ate more than all previous eaters.

Consider three pancake eaters who eat, in order, 1, 2 and 5 pancakes

For person 1 nothing happens! The for loop starts at i = 1 and person 1 is in i = 0;

For person 2

```
if ( 2>0) // true, enter
{   
    temp = 2;
    cout << "The person who eaten most number is " << 2 <<endl;
}
```

output: The person who eaten most number is 2

For person 3

```
if ( 5>2) // true, enter
{   
    temp = 5;
    cout << "The person who eaten most number is " << 5 <<endl;
}
```

output: The person who eaten most number is 5

Note the number of pancakes, not the person who at them was printed.

Persons 4 through 10, who abstained from eating, are also processed:

```
if ( 0>5) // false, skip
if ( 0>5) // false, skip
if ( 0>5) // false, skip
if ( 0>5) // false, skip
if ( 0>5) // false, skip
if ( 0>5) // false, skip
if ( 0>5) // false, skip
```

So the output is

```
The person who eaten most number is 2
The person who eaten most number is 5
```

Whups.

How to fix this:

Throw it all out. Sorry. It's not worth fixing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits> // needed for std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()

int main ()
{
    int numPancakes = 0;
    int person;
    int mostPancakes = 0;
    int ateMost = 0;

    for ( person = 1; person <= 10; person++) // for persons 1 through 10
    {
        std::cout << "Please enter the number of pancakes eaten by person "
                  << person << " : " << std::endl;
        while (!(std::cin >> numPancakes) && numPancakes < 0)
        { // user put in a bad value. Keep asking until they get it right
            std::cin.clear(); // clear error flag
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            // Throw out any other garbage the user fed in up to the end of the line
            std::cout << "Please enter the number of pancakes eaten by person "
                      << person << " : " << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "Person " << person << " ate " << numPancakes
                  << " cakes in the morning! " << std::endl;
        if (numPancakes > mostPancakes)
        {
            mostPancakes = numPancakes;
            ateMost = person;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "The person who ate the most pancakes is " << ateMost << std::endl;
}
```

Note this does not handle ties.

Comment: @Walter Not seeing it. Expand, please.

Answer (score 0):

You should not cout during the for loop. The for loop is there to find the person who eats the most pancakes, you cannot know who that person is until *after* the for loop terminates.

Instead, during the for loop keep track of who ate the most pancakes by:

1. declare an int to represent the index of the person who ate the most pancakes. Do this *before* the for loop.
2. Inside the if inside of your for loop, set that int to be equal to i.
3. cout that values (along with any other info such as maximum number of pancakes eaten) *after* the for loop terminates.

Edit: change int temp to int temp = 0

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains too many unnecessary variables. Moreover, you're approach doesn't work out the person who ate most pancakes, but the number of pancakes they ate.

Also, you should limit the scope of any variables to the necessary minimum (to avoid errors) and give them meaningful names (rather than `i` and `z` etc).
Finally, **never** say `using namespace std`.

```
#include <iostream>
int main ()
{   
    int pancakes[10];          // the number of pancakes each person had

    // 1.  intialise pancakes[]
    for(int person=0; person!=10; ++person) { // loop to read data from stdin
        std::cout << "Please enter the number of pancakes eaten by person " 
                  << person++ << " : ";
        std::cin  >> pancakes[person];
        std::cout << "Person " << person << " has eaten " << pancakes[person]
                  << " cakes in morning! " << std::endl;
    }

    // 2. find the first person who ate most
    int ate_most=0;            // only need one variable: person who ate most
                               // initially, person 0 is our candidate
    for(int person=1; person!=10; ++person)    // loop to check other persons
      if(pancakes[person] > pancakes[ate_most])
        ate_most=person;

    // 3. print out result
    std::cout << "Person " << ate_most << " has eaten most pancakes, namely "
              << pancakes[ate_most] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, could you tell why should we not use 'using namespaces std' ? it it sad to tell  that the code does not seem solving the problem rather confused more.

Comment: @QasimAli ? I didn't understand your second sentence. There are two reason why you shouldn't `using namespace std`. 1) If done in a header file, you inadvertently pollute the global namespace with the contents of `std` *for every file that `#include`s your header*. 2) If done elsewhere, you cannot use symbol names that clash with those in `std` (and there are many most of which you don't know), including future additions (either by changes to the standard or by `#include`ing more standard header files later).